# How spamming entries in website database using the same IP address is possible?

Tags: webserver, sql-server, sqlmap

I am working in a private company as VAPT Auditor. I am currently testing one of our project website which contains common features like login, sign up, etc. I mostly do manual testing using BurpSuite and etc but sometimes I also use automation tools such as SQLmap, intruder, etc.

The problem is we are getting lots of spam junk entries in the database for sign-ups and login and the entries are coming from the same IP address which I have used in past. I don't have a static IP, so the public IP keeps changing. For example, today my IP is 103.206.137.13.

After a few days, we get lots of junk entries on the sign-up page at night using this same IP address which I have used in past, but during the day.

Today we got some fake entries from the IP address which was assigned to me 20 days ago.

Also the junk entries look like SQL Injection queries.

We have implemented rate limiting based on IP address on site so maximum 3 concurrent entries are allowed from the same IP.

My guess was a timing issue in servers. Like I used automation tools during a test but some entries were delayed in database, so it is appearing after a few days but our developer says it is not possible.

Why this is happening? What can be the reason behind this?

Here is a sample of one log from the server

```
[21/Jan/2023:12:23:20 +0530] "POST sitepath/register.php HTTP/2.0" 200 4375 "https://sitepath/register.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0"
```

Comment: That log sample doesn't have an IP and doesn't show SQL injection or anything malicious.  So I'm not sure what its value is.

Comment: There isn't a lot of info here to help. Maybe you have scheduled tests that run at night? Maybe your device is compromised? Maybe someone in your area has the same IP from the same ISP? Have you checked the logs from your machine or your network to rule out that it isn't you? Have you called your ISP to ask if their customers share IPs? All-in-all, this doesn't look like a security problem.

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses for home users, i.e. users on DSL, cable or similar, are often reassigned after a while. Details depend on the ISP. And in the context of NAT or CG-NAT there can also be many users behind the same IP address. Use of CG-NAT by ISP is very common today because of the shortage of IPv4 addresses. Blocking or rate limiting solely based on the IP address can thus result in false positives.